# Biometric matching with futronic sdk using nodejs server

Tags: c, fingerprint, node-ffi

I have successfully taken bio-metric prints and posted to the node server using the futronic sdk. I want to be able to use this library likewise for matching in the server because that's where the bio-metric prints for all users are stored. I stubbled upon the `node-ffi` library that helps define equivalent C functions that I have exported and compiled it down to a .dll file.

Now the challenge here is that I have tried to port the `ftrAnsiSDK` functions but the `ftrScanAPI.dll` and the `ftrAnsiSDK.dll` file could not be compiled together. It gives this error:

`...collect2.exe   [Error] ld returned 5 exit status`

When I compile and export the functions that are not dependent on these two libraries, my code works fine and the functions are easily exported and used in the node server. Please can any one give me a hint?

Here is the [link to the repo](https://github.com/nondefyde/futronic_fucntion_export). It consists of the lib and .dll library that is been used.

For the server code here is a snippet of what I am trying to achieve:

```
var libm = ffi.Library('lib/visystem', {
'HelloWorld': [ 'void', [] ],
'PrintErrorMessage': [ 'void', ['int'] ],
'CaprureImage': [ 'int', ['int','int','int'] ]});
```

The `HelloWord` and `PrintErrorMessages` are methods that I used as a test case to ensure the functions are being exported before I proceeded to the main functions (you can see the function definition in from the code in the repo.. ) that depends on the [futronic lin and sdk](http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_sdk_win.html).

I am currently using a 64-bit operation system and I installed the same program on a 32-bit machine to be sure, but it still did not compile and export the function. The code editor I am using is Dev++C.

Can anyone help or even give me hint on how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

As a disclaimer, I'm not familiar with the Dev-C++ IDE or MinGW development.

However, after a cursory look at your github repo, according to your **libvisystem.def** file, it appears that the only functions that are exported by your DLL are:

- HelloWorld
- PrintErrorMessage
- ReadTemplateFile
- SaveBmpFile
- SaveTemplateFile

This is also confirmed when looking at the **libvisystem.a** library header:

[image]

So you should probably start by manually add the rest of the exported functions in your **dll.h** to the def file, in a similar manner to the ones that are already there, and see if that changes anything.

---

**NOTE:**

I'm not sure whether the *__declspec(dllexport)* directive is ignored by the Dev-C++ compiler/linker and it uses the def file instead. Perhaps others on SO have an idea.